# How to read Firestore data from a Map field type?

Tags: ios, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore data is set up like this:
[image]

This is how I'm reading the data:

```
for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                    
  let recipeFromFirestore = Recipe(
    glutenFree: doc["glutenFree"] as! Bool,
    dairyFree: doc["dairyFree"] as! Bool,
    cheap: doc["cheap"] as! Bool)
                    
  recipes.append(recipeFromFirestore)
}
```

These are my `Recipe` and `ExtendedIngredients` structs:

```
struct Recipe: Codable {
    var glutenFree: Bool?
    var dairyFree: Bool?
    var cheap: Bool?
    var extendedIngredients: [ExtendedIngredients]? = nil
}

struct ExtendedIngredients: Codable {
    var aisle: String?
    var image: String?
    var name: String?
    var amount: Double?
    var unit: String?
}
```

How can I go about reading the `array` of Map type data in my `extendedIngredients` field in Firestore? I'm not sure how to include that in my `let recipeFromFirestore` code.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get all of my data, including the Map type by using the [Codable API](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/).

```
docRef.getDocument { document, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                self.errorMessage = "Error getting document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
            else {
                if let document = document {
                    do {
                        self.recipe = try document.data(as: Recipe.self)
                        
        let recipeFromFirestore = Recipe(
        glutenFree: self.recipe!.glutenFree, 
        dairyFree: self.recipe!.dairyFree,
        cheap: self.recipe!.cheap,
        extendedIngredients: self.recipe!.extendedIngredients)
                        
                        self.recipes.append(recipeFromFirestore)

                    }
                    catch {
                        print("Line 136: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I did not need to do any explicit mapping with this approach.